# Fill a bow with weights

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, optimization, greedy

I am trying to select the maximum of weights I can, to fill a box which can supports a weight of C. For that I have sorted the list of weights V, I am reading them from n to 0 (index) and for each n I want to compute each maximum I can have who doesn't go over C. I am filling the table T with every maximum of weight I found who are equals to C or the nearest they can for an n.

Thank you for you help, I have already dedicated a great amount of time for the code and I am still lost at the end, where I want to verified by recursion if the sum of V[n] will be or not too high, I don't think the end of my code is well thinked.

````
V=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
C = 9

def Vmax(V, n, C, T):
    if n ==-1:
        return(T)
    else:
        if C < V[n]:
            Vmax(V, n-1, C, T)
        else:
            if V[n]== C:
                T.append(V[n])
                Vmax(V, n-1, C, T)

# Troubles starts here     

            elif V[n] < C:
                for k in range(1,n):
                    if k - n == -2:
                        T.append(V[n])
                    if V[n] + Vmax(V, n-k, C, T) < C:
                        T.append(V[n] + Vmax(V, n-k, C, T))
                    else:
                        Vmax(V, n-1, C, T)

print(Vmax(V, len(V)-1, C, T))```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"Troubles starts here" [sic] is not a problem specification.  Also, please consult the many discussions of the "target sum" problem on SO and other sites.

Comment: One of the easiest ways to better understand what your code is doing is to use *meaningful* variable names. I look at your code and see a bunch of n,k,T,C,V, and have absolutely no idea what the heck is going on. But if the variable had a name that describes what it represents, my understanding would increase greatly. You may think you understand it those cryptic names, but you won't next week. Use meaningful variable names.